# how to create syncfusion dropdownlist in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, selectlist, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion dropdownlist. I want to create a dropdownlist for blood group in my form. How can I do that in angularjs?

```
<input type="text" ej-dropdownlist e-datasource="BloodGroup_List" e-value="Name" ng-model="employee.bloodgroup">
```

In my controller I have written,

```
$scope.bloodgroup = [{ "Id": "1", "Name": "O+" },
                                  { "Id": "2", "Name": "O-" },
                                  { "Id": "3", "Name": "A+" },
                                  { "Id": "4", "Name": "A-" },
                                  { "Id": "5", "Name": "B+" },
                                  { "Id": "6", "Name": "B-" },
                                  { "Id": "7", "Name": "AB+" },
                                  { "Id": "8", "Name": "AB-" }];

    $scope.BloodGroup_List = $scope.bloodgroup;
```

The above code is not working, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the data source to the corresponding attributes in "fields" property.

```
<input type="text" id="bloodgroup" ej-dropdownlist e-datasource="BloodGroup_List" e-fields-text="Name" e-fields-value="Name" e-fields-id="Id" e-value="value">
```

In the script, inject 'ejAngular' and specify your values as shown below

```
    angular.module('DropCtrl', ['ejangular'])
       .controller('DropDownCtrl', function ($scope) {
           $scope.bloodgroup = [{ "Id": "1", "Name": "O+" },
                      { "Id": "2", "Name": "O-" },
                      { "Id": "3", "Name": "A+" },
                      { "Id": "4", "Name": "A-" },
                      { "Id": "5", "Name": "B+" },
                      { "Id": "6", "Name": "B-" },
                      { "Id": "7", "Name": "AB+" },
                      { "Id": "8", "Name": "AB-" }];
           $scope.BloodGroup_List = $scope.bloodgroup;
           $scope.value = "AB-";
       });
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="bloodgroupvalue in bloodgroup" value="{{bloodgroupvalue.Id}}">{{bloodgroupvalue.Name}}</option>
      </select>
```

or

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="bloodgroupvalue.Name for bloodgroupvalue in bloodgroup">
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `e-fields-text="Name"` to show text on in the dropdown then it will bind the value to that `ng-model`

**HTML**

```
<input id="test" type="text" ej-dropdownlist e-datasource="BloodGroup_List" e-fields-text="Name" 
e-fields-value="Name" ng-model="employee.bloodgroup" e-change="selectedBloodGroup"/>
```

**CODE**

```
$scope.selectedBloodGroup = function(args) {
    $scope.employee.bloodgroup = args.value;
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SrJH9puki8E7Cc3XH2uB?p=preview)